# Using ServiceStack to upload image files

Tags: c#, servicestack

We have a requirement to upload images using ServiceStack APIs.

I am aware of two possible ways:

1) Use JSON object to upload file (Using BASE64 string).
2) Use "multipart/form-data"

Is there any other way of uploading files using ServiceStack? Which is better in terms of best practices?

Answer (score 13):

The best way to upload files in ServiceStack is to just do a normal HTTP File upload see the [source code](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/blob/master/ImageResizer/Global.asax.cs#L63-L70) for [imgur.servicestack.net](http://imgur.servicestack.net/) or [file uploads in RestFiles](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/RestFiles/RestFiles.ServiceInterface/FilesService.cs#L54-L58) for examples.

If you don't want to send `multipart/form-data` then use a binary format like [Protocol Buffers support in ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Protobuf-format) and send `byte[]` to avoid the computational and payload overhead of encoding binary files in a text format.

Comment: I like protocol buffers. Can it be easily implemented by various mobile clients? I am looking for a solution that can be consumed by variety of mobile apps without much struggle for developers.

Comment: @Black-Baba Use `multipart/form-data` for the best interoperability as it will allow any HTTP Client on any platform that supports it to be able to upload files to your service.