# ServiceStack endpoint for uploading image files

Tags: c#, http, servicestack

I want to implement a ServiceStack endpoint enabling user to upload an icon. I have two questions:

1. Where should I put the image in the request? Currently I use a Firefox extension called `HttpRequester` and add my image as a file in contents part.
2. Where should I look for the content in the request? According to some other posts, `request.Files` should have it but it is empty.

Comment: `Request.Files` should work if the client is sending `multipart/form-data`.  Also, check out [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475720/using-servicestack-to-upload-image-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the working code (ServiceStack 4).

Model:

```
[Route("/api/upload", Verbs = "POST")]
public class UploadRequest: IReturn<UploadResponse>
{
     public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}

public class UploadResponse
{
    public ResponseStatus Response { get; set; }
}
```

Service:

```
public UploadResponse Post(UploadRequest request)
{
    Request.Files.ForEach(f => ProcessFile(f));
    return null;
}

private void ProcessFile(IHttpFile file)
{
     // logic here
}
```

Comment: I now think that this `Date` property is not needed. The issue might indeed be with wrong format type. There is an example on the SS customer forum: https://forums.servicestack.net/t/how-to-upload-a-file-and-post-json-data-in-the-same-request/3318